# Cannot Receive Firebase Notification on multiple device by sending notify to specific topic

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My purpose is to send notification to specific login customer

Example : Customer ID : 1 , I need to subscribe them to topic "/topic/customer_1"

On JavaScript Site, after I got the permission token , I've called the server site to subscribe the customer to the topic by their token.

If I login by using PC , Then I can get TOKEN_A

If I login by using same account on mobile , Then I can get TOKEN_B

```
function IntitalizeFireBaseMessaging() {

    messaging

        .requestPermission()

        .then(function () {

            console.log("Notification Permission");

            return messaging.getToken();

        })

        .then(function (token) {

            console.log("Token : "+token);

            $.ajax({
                url : '/firebase-subscribe-customer-to-topic?token=' + token,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

            document.getElementById("token").innerHTML=token;

        })

        .catch(function (reason) {

            console.log(reason);

        });

}
```

This is Server Side (PHP)

```
$token = $_GET['token'];
$customer_id = 1;
$headers = array
    ('Authorization: key=MY_FIREBASE_KEY' ,
    'Content-Type: application/json');

$ch = curl_init();
// browser token you can get it via ajax from client side

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/$token/rel/topics/customer_" . $customer_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now the problem is that I can receive the notification only on PC and not on mobile.

And here is the send notification code for firebase

```
 $payload = [
            'click_action' => 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            'tab_index' => 3
        ];
 $this->fireBaseNootification("/topics/customer_1" ,"Title","Description","https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png",$payload);


private function fireBaseNootification($to, $title, $message, $img = "", $datapayload = ""){
    $msg = urlencode($message);
    $data = array(
        'title'=>$title,
        'sound' => "default",
        'msg'=>$msg,
        'data'=>$datapayload,
        'body'=>$message,
        'color' => "#79bc64"
    );
    // if($img){
    //     $data["image"] = $img;
    //     $data["style"] = "picture";
    //     $data["picture"] = $img;
    // }
    $fields = array(
        'to'=>$to,
        'notification'=>$data,
        'data'=>$datapayload,
        'content_available' => true,
        "priority" => "high",
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=MY_SERVER_KEY',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $result;
}
```

Could you tell which part I was wrong?